# Not finding the option of axis2 preferences in rad8

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis, rad

How to use apache axis2 with rad8. I am not finding the option of axis2 preferences as present in eclipse. 
What steps are required to generate client from wsdl in rad 8 using axis2?

Thanks in advance.

Nitish

Answer (score 0):

You can use the thinclient library in WAS 8 with a JAX-WS runtime target when [generating a Web Service Client](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/com.ibm.webservice.doc/topics/jaxws/tsampappjaxws.html). IBM uses Axis2 for this JAX-WS implementation.